# How to Stream Audio to Raspberry Pi via PulseAudio RTP Unicast?

Tags: raspberry-pi, rtp, pulseaudio, kodi, unicast

I am trying to stream audio from a Linux Mint Desktop to a RaspberryPi 3B running LibreELEC (Kodi) using PulseAudio RTP. I can successfully stream the audio with RTP multicast:

Desktop:

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=rtp
pactl load-module module-rtp-send source=rtp.monitor
```

Pi:

```
pactl load-module module-rtp-recv latency_msec=50
```

But I would like to use RTP unicast to avoid UDP packet flooding associated with RTP multicast. This is what I have tried:

Desktop:

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=rtp
pactl load-module module-rtp-send source=rtp.monitor destination_ip=192.168.1.117
```

Pi:

```
pactl load-module module-rtp-recv latency_msec=50
```

(I get "failed to load module" if I add 'sap_address=192.168.1.200')

No audio comes through the pi. Might someone know how to get the unicast working?

Answer (score 4):

Simple fix:

```
pactl load-module module-rtp-recv latency_msec=50 sap_address=0.0.0.0
```

It now loads the "module-rtp-recv" module without an error and streams successfully